# Библиотека для графиков на js

Tags: javascript, график, поиск-библиотек

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто ведает не подскажите бесплатную библиотеку для отрисовки данного графика на js ?

Comment: https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo

Comment: можно на d3 такое изобразить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) https://www.highcharts.com/ - попроще в установке, но бесплатная для **ЛИЧНОГО ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ**, для коммерческих проектов довольно дорогая.

2) https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery?hl=ru - я пользуюсь гугл-чартами. Не такие навороченные, но без головной боли с лицензией.

3) http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/ - доводилось пару раз работать с flot, тоже не плохо, но гугловые нравятся больше.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример такого графика собранный при помощи библиотеки d3

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 110, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 330, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = +svg.attr("height") - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height2]])
    .on("brush end", brushed);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var area = d3.area()
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
    .x(d => x(d.date))
    .y0(height)
    .y1(d => y(d.price));

var area2 = d3.area()
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
    .x(d => x2(d.date))
    .y0(height2)
    .y1(d => y2(d.price));

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width-1)
    .attr("height", height-1);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

var data = Array(100).fill(0).map((e,i) => ({
  date: Date.now() + i*100000,
  price: Math.random()*100
}))

x.domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, d =>  d.price)]);
x2.domain(x.domain());
y2.domain(y.domain());

focus.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area);

focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(yAxis);

context.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area2);

context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
    .call(xAxis2);

context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(brush)
    .call(brush.move, x.range());

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "zoom")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoom);

function brushed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") 
    return; 
  var s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();
  x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
      .translate(-s[0], 0));
}

function zoomed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush")
    return; 
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
}
```

```css
.area {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}

.zoom {
  cursor: move;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="630" height="400"></svg>
```